# ElectronJS - ask for root access one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, openvpn

I have developed a VPN application that uses openVPN on electronJS to connect with.

The problem is, that everytime the user connects to a VPN-server it asks for root-access. Which is not user-friendly.

Is there a way to ask user for root access only once, so the whole app has it and the user is not required to type in the password every time the sudo command needs to be run?

Thank you.